# griddle-react API not found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, griddle

Thanks in advance. I took over an old project and have to fix some problems. It's using the [griddle-react](http://griddlegriddle.github.io/Griddle/docs/api/), and the code like this:

```
 import Griddle from 'griddle-react';
 ......

        <Griddle
          useExternal
          externalSetPage={ this.setSearchPage }
          externalChangeSort={ noop }
          externalSetFilter={ noop }
          externalSetPageSize={ noop }
          externalMaxPage={ this.state.totalPages }
          externalCurrentPage={ this.state.currentPage }
          useGriddleStyles={ false }
          tableClassName="table table-bordered data-table"
          results={ this.state.listings }
          columns={ columns }
          columnMetadata={ columnMetadatas }
          noDataMessage="No search result"
        />
```

But when I looked through the official doc, I found nothing about **columnMetadata, columns**

I checked the package.json file:

```
  "griddle-react": "0.6.0",
```

Am I going to the wrong place? Or has the version0.6 been deprecated?Where could I find that version0.6 API documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is their old doc [link](https://griddlegriddle.github.io/v0-docs/properties.html)

If it does not help another option is to look at the source code in their GitHub.
Here is a version [0.6.0](https://github.com/GriddleGriddle/Griddle/tree/v0.6.0) tag.

Answer (score 0):

> Use the columns property to set the default columns in a Griddle grid.

and

> The column meta data property is used to specify column properties that are not part of the result data object. For instance, if you want to specify a displayName that is different than the property name in the result data, the `columnMetadata` property is where this would be defined.

You can find the documentation for **columnMetadata** and **columns** [here](https://griddlegriddle.github.io/v0-docs/customization.html)